# What language feature can allow transition from visitor to sequence?

Tags: language-agnostic, ienumerable, sequence, visitor-pattern

I will use C# syntax  since I am familiar with it, but it is not really language-specific.

---

Let's say we want to provide an API to go over a `Tree` and do something with each `Node`.

Solution 1: `void Visit(Tree tree, Action<Node> action)`
It takes a `tree`, and calls `action` on each node in the tree.

Solution 2: `IEnumerable<Node> ToEnumerable(Tree tree)`
It converts `tree` to a flat lazy sequence so we can go over and call `action` on each node.

---

Now, let's see how we can convert one API to another.

It is pretty trivial to provide `Visit` on top of `ToEnumerable`:

```
void Visit(Tree tree, Action<Node> action) {
    ToEnumerable(tree).ForEach(action);
}
```

However, is there a concept/feature in any language that will allow to provide `ToEnumerable` on top of `Visit` (as lazy sequence, so list is not created in advance)?

Comment: Not sure what you’re asking for … do you want a class / pattern which would automatically create a lazy `IEnumerable` for an object hierarchy, given an appropriate visitor method? (If so, I suspect the answer is “no” unless the object also supports a *flat* enumeration which traverses just the “children” of a given object).

Comment: @KonradRudolph yes. I do not necessary want a class/pattern though, more like a language feature or concept. I have a feeling continuations might be related, but I am not familiar enough with them.

Comment: I think this is a property of the structure, not of any language feature. The purest (as in most abstract) representation of this I know is Haskell's Foldable (http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Foldable.html), see in particular foldMap.

Comment: One thing I found that seems relevant: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164086.aspx

Comment: Are you looking for implementation techniques? Or just for the concept itself? Implementation techniques will vary wildly in different languages (and even within a language there's many ways to do it).

Comment: @MauricioScheffer I am looking for a concept (exactly because of your point), now I think it is coroutine/continuation, but I haven't got all the details sorted out yet.

Comment: In that case, I'd classify coroutines/continuations as an implementation technique, not as the pure concept (which IMHO applies to the structure, not to the language). For example, you won't see any continuations in Haskell's Data.Foldable.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but in Python, you can create iterable interface on any object.
So you would just add special method `__iter__` (which will yield nodes while traversing the tree).
The `visit` procedure is then just about iterating through `Tree` object and calling `action` on each node.

Comment: That is on implementing `visit` on top of `__iter__`. But I have an object that implements `visit`, how do can I define `__iter__` on it, using `visit`?

Comment: You can specify that `visit` method accepts any iterable. Passing Tree as this iterable will work, if you specify  `__iter__` method in the Tree.
Sorry if I misunderstood you.

Comment: Let's say `Tree` does not have `__iter__`. It only have `visit`. You can't change `Tree`. You want to make `iter` that will iterate the `Tree`, using its `visit`. How would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing the code that will visit each node (as with a tree), it's possible to have an iterator call iterators for each branch, and perform a `yield return` on leaf nodes.  This approach will work, and is very simple, but has the serious disadvantage that it's very easy to end up with code that will be very readable but execute very slowly.  Some other questions and answers on this site will offer insight as to how to traverse trees efficiently within an iterator.

If the "tree" was just an example, and what you really have is a class which exposes a routine to call some delegate upon each node (similar to `List.ForEach()`), but does not expose an `IEnumerable`, you may be able to use the former to produce a `List`, which you could then iterate.  Use something like `var myList = new List<someThing>(); myCollection.ForEach( (x) => myList.Add(x) );` and then you may be able to enumerate `myList`.

If even that isn't sufficient, because the objects that were added to the list may not be valid by the time enumeration is complete, it may in rare cases be possible to use multiple threading to accomplish what's needed.  For example, if you have two sorted collections whose `ForEach` method prepares each items for use, does the specified action, and then cleans up each item before proceeding to the next, and if you need to interleave the actions on items from two *independent* collections, one might be able to iterate the collections on separate threads, and use synchronization primitives so each thread will wait as necessary for the other.

Note that collections which only expose themselves via `ForEach` method are apt to restrict access during the execution of such a `ForEach` (if such restriction weren't necessary, they would probably implement `IEnumerable`).  It may be possible for the "item action" called by one `ForEach` to perform another `ForEach` on the same collection on the same thread, since the latter `ForEach` would have to complete before the former one could resume.  While one `ForEach` is running, however, an attempt to call a `ForEach` on a second thread would likely either malfunction or wait for the first operation to complete.  If the first `ForEach` was waiting for some action by the second, deadlock would result.  Because of this, scenarios where multi-threading will work better than simply building a `List` are rare.  Nonetheless, there are a few cases where it may be helpful (e.g. the above-mentioned "zipper" operation on independent collections).

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer. I think the threading example is the nearest to what I am asking about, but it is a specific implementation/approach to a more generic pattern, which in itself does not require threads, and only requires ability to save state/restore state. Now I think that is what called continuation, but I'll have to research it a bit more before finalizing my understanding. Thanks again.

Comment: @AndreyShchekin: Some objects allow a state to be saved and then restored after any arbitrary combination of save/restore operations; other objects enforce a LIFO sequence, such that if the state is saved to X and then later saved to Y, restoring state X will invalidate Y (if it hasn't already been invalidated via other means).  Continuations are a means by which state can be held and acted upon in arbitrary sequence.  Such mechanisms can be more versatile than ones which enforce strict stacking protocol, but can also be more complicated from standpoints of both implementation and semantics.

Comment: @AndreyShchekin: Note that being able to save/restore state is somewhat different from being able to hold and act upon state.  The former can be used in cooperative multitasking between two tasks, but any time operation switches between tasks, the task being suspended must save its state and the task being awakened must restore its state.  By contrast, if each stack can act upon its own private state, the two tasks can run simultaneously without interference.

Answer (score 0):

I think now I understand the idea. The concept that I need here is called [first-class continuations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) or, specifically, [call/cc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-with-current-continuation). The confusing thing about it for me is that C# already provides a limited implementation of this concept in `yield return`, but it is not applicable to my scenario.

So if C# provided full implementation, the solution would look like:

```
IEnumerable<Node> ToEnumerable(Tree tree) {
    tree.Visit(node => magic yield return node);
}
```

where `magic yield return` instead of returning sequence from `node => ...` lambda returns next element from `ToEnumerable`.

However, this answer is still not complete as I do not see the exact correlation between `yield return` and `call/cc`. I will update the answer when I understand this.

Comment: If you're interested in doing catamorphisms (i.e. folds) with continuations I recommend this series of blog posts: http://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/06/07/catamorphisms-part-seven/